# Problem installing nginx on ubuntu 20.04 AWS EC2 node

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04

I try to install nginx on an Ubuntu 20.04 AWS EC2 server by doing:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install nginx
```

However the last command fails:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the AMI id, AMI name and region? I install nginx without error.

Comment: ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20201026, eu-west (Ireland)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Comment: Yes! Super! Problem solved. Thanks a lot!